# Index Error: Unable to print cost_function

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to run a for loop to print the cost functions for three different slopes and bias = 0 by defining a function. The dataset has 5 rows and cost function is to predict marks based on attendance.
I am able to print cost function if I define three separate functions for each value of slope. Here is my code:

```
dataset = {"Attendance":[100, 87, 15, 63, 47], "Marks": [100, 95, 6, 73, 50]}
Marks = pd.DataFrame(dataset, columns = ["Attendance", "Marks"])
bias = 0
slope = {"values": [-1, 0, 3]}
slope = pd.DataFrame(slope)
def error():
  a = []
  sum_of_squared_error = 0
  for i in range(len(slope)):
    for j in range(0, len(Marks)):
      x = Marks.iloc[j, 0]
      y = Marks.iloc[j, 1]
      sum_of_squared_error += (y - (slope.iloc[0, i]*x + bias)) ** 2
      cost_function = sum_of_squared_error / (2 * len(Marks))
    a.append(cost_function)
  return a
error()
```

I am getting this error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-126-1bf54ede9ae1> in <module>()
     13       a.append(cost_function)
     14   return a
---> 15 error()

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _validate_integer(self, key, axis)
   2061         len_axis = len(self.obj._get_axis(axis))
   2062         if key >= len_axis or key < -len_axis:
-> 2063             raise IndexError("single positional indexer is out-of-bounds")
   2064 
   2065     def _getitem_tuple(self, tup: Tuple):

IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
```

Comment: You have `for i in range(len(slope)):` *and* `for i in range(0, len(Marks)):`: `i` is used twice, in both loops.

Comment: I changed the second for-loop to j and changed the indentation for return but same problem.

Comment: Made the changes. Could you please let me know whats the issue?

Comment: For every iteration in for i in range(len(slope)): I want to put the three cost_functions in a list - a. and print them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't accessing the elements of your slope df correctly. `slope.shape` returns `(3, 1)` so you want to iterate through the row number, not the column number.

`sum_of_squared_error += (y - (slope.iloc[0, i]*x + bias)) ** 2` should be: `sum_of_squared_error += (y - (slope.iloc[i, 0]*x + bias)) ** 2`

In addition, you should have sum_of_squared_error reset to 0 between the inner and outer loop:

```
import pandas as pd

dataset = {"Attendance":[100, 87, 15, 63, 47], "Marks": [100, 95, 6, 73, 50]}
Marks = pd.DataFrame(dataset, columns = ["Attendance", "Marks"])
bias = 0
slope = {"values": [-1, 0, 3]}
slope = pd.DataFrame(slope)
def error():
  a = []
  sum_of_squared_error = 0
  for i in range(len(slope)):
    for j in range(0, len(Marks)):
      x = Marks.iloc[j, 0]
      y = Marks.iloc[j, 1]
      sum_of_squared_error += (y - (slope.iloc[i, 0]*x + bias)) ** 2
    cost_function = sum_of_squared_error / (2 * len(Marks))
    sum_of_squared_error = 0
    a.append(cost_function)
  return a
error()
```

Output:

```
>>> error()
[10147.0, 2689.0, 9081.4]
```

Comment: That works but one issue. The output should be ```[10147.0, 2689.0, 9081.4]```. It is adding the the values to the next values in the list in each iteration.

Comment: Updated. You should reset the sum_of_squared error variable whenever you run the outer loop.

Comment: I made the changes. The final code looks like this.                         ```def error():
  sum_of_squared_error = 0
  a = []
  for i in range(len(slope)):
    sum_of_squared_error1 = 0
    for j in range(0, len(Marks)):
      x = Marks.iloc[j, 0]
      y = Marks.iloc[j, 1]
      sum_of_squared_error1 += (y - (slope.iloc[i, 0]*x + bias)) ** 2
      sum_of_squared_error = sum_of_squared_error1
      cost_function = sum_of_squared_error / (2 * len(Marks))     
    a.append(cost_function)
  return a
error()```

Comment: Nice! As long as you get the same output, you should be in good shape

Comment: Thank you. Good luck!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219464/discussion-between-nikhil-kumar-macharla-and-derek-o).

Answer (score 1):

The error appears on line -

```
    sum_of_squared_error += (y - (slope.iloc[0, i]*x + bias)) ** 2
```

This happens because `iloc` can take values only till `length-1` of the axis.

Ref - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html

In your case [0,i] takes the following values -

- [0,0] ---  OK
- [0,1] --- NOT OK
- [0,2] --- NOT OK

Because, there are no column - 1 & 2 in `slope`